# Get all the values of a particular key

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, mongodb-query

I have a data in mongoDB, I want to retrieve all the values of a key `"category"` using python code. I have tried several ways but in every case I have to give the "value" to retrieve. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
{
   id = "my_id1"
   tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3],
   category: "movie",
},
{
   id = "my_id2"
   tags: [tag3, tag6, tag9],
   category: "tv",
},
{
   id = "my_id3"
   tags: [tag2, tag6, tag8],
   category: "movie",
}
```

I want the output as

```
category: "movie"
category: "tv"
category: "movie"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This Should Work

```
db.test.find({},{"category":1});
```

Answer (score -2):

Pymongo's `distinct()` method returns a list of all values associated with a key across all documents in a collection.

The following code:

```
db.collection.distinct('category')
```

should return the following list:

```
['movie', 'tv', 'movie']
```

Comment: i think this will only return ['movie', 'tv'] because distinct() shows only the unique values.