# get all the values of particular key using PeriodicTask of celerybeatmongo.models

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, celerybeat

I am using PeriodicTask of celerybeatmongo.models to schedule my tasks. I have a requirement where I need to fetch all the values of particular key. Something like this - [Get all the values of a particular key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282812/get-all-the-values-of-a-particular-key), but using celerybeatmongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot many trail and error found the solution.
The below is the small piece of code that does the required task:

```
    connect(host=mongo_uri)
    tasks_list = []
    for doc in PeriodicTask.objects():
        if doc.enabled:
            tasks_list.append(doc.name)
    disconnect()
```